# Google OR example for column generation

Tags: optimization, or-tools, operations-research

Are there any examples of the code for the Column generation problem (cutting stock problem or any other problem) using google OR tools in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as the name suggests, this does the job:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/cpp/strawberry_fields_with_column_generation.cc